# Generalising over two structs

Tags: generics, types, rust

I have two independent libraries (distinct crates), each defining a struct and a function to build such a struct, if possible (for simplicity, I put everything into one module):

```
struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

impl Foo {
    fn make_foo(a: &str) -> Option<Foo> {
        Some(Foo {})
    }
}

impl Bar {
    fn make_bar(b: &str) -> Option<Bar> {
        Some(Bar {})
    }
}
```

I now want to handle the two structs in the same way, independent of whether I actually have a `Foo` or a `Bar`:

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn do_something() -> ();
}
impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn do_something() -> () {
        ()
    }
}
impl SomeTrait for Bar {
    fn do_something() -> () {
        ()
    }
}
```

Since the size of `SomeTrait` is unknown at compile time, I can't simply `let a: Option<SomeTrait> = Foo::make_foo("abc")`. So I tried wrap it in a `Box` (*before* unpacking the `Option`):

```
fn main() {
    let f: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = Foo::make_foo("abc").map(Box::new)
}
```

But still the compiler complains:

```
error: mismatched types [E0308]
    let b: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = Foo::new().map(Box::new);
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `std::option::Option<Box<SomeTrait>>`
note:    found type `std::option::Option<Box<Foo>>`
```

I tried to use `as` for casting, but that didn't work since these are all non-scalar types.

How do I solve this (without touching the implementation of `Foo` and `Bar`)? I feel like I'm trying to apply patterns from classical OOP-languages to Rust's trait system.

In the end, I want to be able to do something like:

```
fn main() {
    let arg = 5;
    let x: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = match arg {
        4 => Foo::make_foo("abc").map(Box::new),
        _ => Bar::make_bar("abc").map(Box::new),
    };

    x.do_something()
}
```

---

Full example:

```
// Library part
struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Option<Foo> {
        Some(Foo {})
    }
}
impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Option<Bar> {
        Some(Bar {})
    }
}

// My Part
trait SomeTrait {
    fn do_something(&self);
}
impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("foo")
    }
}
impl SomeTrait for Bar {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("bar")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let b: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = match "x" {
        "x" => Foo::new().map(Box::new),
        _ => Bar::new().map(Box::new),
    };
    b.unwrap().do_something();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some additional information on what these impls are supposed to do? It's difficult to reason about this code.

Comment: Hm, I'd test for myself if you had provided a complete example, but I guess maybe explicitly supplying type arguments to the `Box` constructor could help? `Foo::new().map(Box::<SomeTrait>::new)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is as beautiful as it gets, but I got this code working:

```
// Library part
struct Foo {}
struct Bar {}

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Option<Foo> {Some(Foo {})}
}
impl Bar {
    fn new() -> Option<Bar> {Some(Bar {})}
}

// My Part
trait SomeTrait {
    fn do_something(&self);
}
impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("foo")
    }
}
impl SomeTrait for Bar {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        println!("bar")
    }
}

fn main () {
    let b: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = match "x" {
        "x" => Foo::new().map(|x| Box::new(x) as Box<SomeTrait>),
        _ => Bar::new().map(|x| Box::new(x) as Box<SomeTrait>)
    };
    b.unwrap().do_something();
}
```

The change here is inside the calls to `map`. Instead of `Box::new`, `|x| Box::new(x) as Box<SomeTrait>`. This first creates a Box of the concrete type, and then casts it to the more generic Box type.

---

I thought it might look more clean if I did the conversion by `.map(Into::into)`, but I'm not sure that panned out as well as hoped. I was surprised to find that there is no default implementation of `From` that does up-casting of `Box`. I got the following working, as another [alternative solution](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%2F%2F%20Library%20part%0Astruct%20Foo%20%7B%7D%0Astruct%20Bar%20%7B%7D%0A%0Aimpl%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Option%3CFoo%3E%20%7BSome(Foo%20%7B%7D)%7D%0A%7D%0Aimpl%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20new()%20-%3E%20Option%3CBar%3E%20%7BSome(Bar%20%7B%7D)%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A%2F%2F%20My%20Part%0Atrait%20SomeTrait%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20do_something(%26self)%3B%0A%7D%0Aimpl%20SomeTrait%20for%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20do_something(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22foo%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0Aimpl%20SomeTrait%20for%20Bar%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20do_something(%26self)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22bar%22)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%2C%20T%3E%20From%3CBox%3CT%3E%3E%20for%20Box%3CSomeTrait%2B%27a%3E%0A%20%20%20%20where%20T%20%3A%20SomeTrait%2B%27a%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20from(b%3A%20Box%3CT%3E)%20-%3E%20Box%3CSomeTrait%2B%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b%20as%20Box%3CSomeTrait%2B%27a%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20b%3A%20Option%3CBox%3CSomeTrait%3E%3E%20%3D%20match%20%22x%22%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22x%22%20%3D%3E%20Foo%3A%3Anew().map(Box%3A%3Anew).map(Into%3A%3Ainto)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20_%20%3D%3E%20Bar%3A%3Anew().map(Box%3A%3Anew).map(Into%3A%3Ainto)%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20b.unwrap().do_something()%3B%0A%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0):

```
impl<'a, T> From<Box<T>> for Box<SomeTrait+'a>
    where T : SomeTrait+'a
{
    fn from(b: Box<T>) -> Box<SomeTrait+'a> {
        b as Box<SomeTrait+'a>
    }
}

fn main () {
    let b: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = match "x" {
        "x" => Foo::new().map(Box::new).map(Into::into),
        _ => Bar::new().map(Box::new).map(Into::into)
    };
    b.unwrap().do_something();
}
```

Comment: You should consider outsourcing the `map(...)` part to a generic function, like described in the comments of the accepted answer.

Comment: @jobach I added another implementation that does a little bit of that. At least the conversion is factored out to a supporting function (`impl From`). This solution looks a bit boiler-platey to me, but I don't know the real world situation this is going into, so it might work :P Anyway; I added it as a possible alternative to look at.

Comment: Even though the other answer was what inspired me for my own solution, this one addresses the problem from the question more directly, so I'm going to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are two general problems with this. The first is you need to have the object represented as a `Option<Box<SomeTrait>>` so setting your variable binding needs to be something like this `let f: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = Some(Box::new(Foo::make_foo("abc")));`

and you need to remove the option part from your make method so you can wrap it properly later.

```
impl Foo {
    fn make_foo(a: &str) -> Foo {
        Foo {}
    }
}
```

The ordering here is important. Option can't hold an unsized trait so it needs to wrap the box.

Second is, a trait can not become a trait object if the trait has methods that don't reference `&self`

A quick except from the rust error docs shows

> Method has no receiver
>
> Methods that do not take a self parameter can't be called since there won't be a way to get a pointer to the method table for them.

So for your trait methods you need

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn do_something(&self);
}
impl SomeTrait for Foo {
    fn do_something(&self) {  }
}
impl SomeTrait for Bar {
    fn do_something(&self) {  }
}
```

Edit:

Since you can not change the make functions, another approach for mapping them properly is adding a return type to the lambda so it knows how to help the compiler agree with the type.

```
let f: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = Foo::make_foo("abc").and_then(|foo| -> Option<Box<SomeTrait>> {
    Some(Box::new(foo))
});
```

Comment: Well, I can't edit the `make_*` methods, since they are part of two libraries. As to the `do_something`: The real functions in my code actually take `&self`, i just tried to removed as much unnecassary context as possible, without realizing I actually broke something by that.

Comment: Well in that case, it probably comes down to the compiler not being able to properly infer your map function. You could maybe try 
`    let f: Option<Box<SomeTrait>> = Foo::make_foo("abc").and_then(|foo| -> Option<Box<SomeTrait>> {
        Some(Box::new(foo))
    });`

Comment: I edited my answer to include that to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: That works. But if combined with e.g. a `match` (see my _edit_ above), it also requires the `.and_then` part to be applied to each match-arm seperately, and cant be wrapped around the `match`.

Comment: Right, in this case you would have to handle the and then within each branch of the match. You could potentially come up with a generic function that could clean it up, at least a little bit. I'll see if I can think of something for it.

Comment: This should work: `fn repack<T: SomeTrait + 'static>(option: Option<T>) -> Option<Box<SomeTrait>> {
    option.and_then(|x| -> Option<Box<SomeTrait>> {Some(Box::new(x))})
}`